# optimize css animations with javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs-directive, css-animations

It is possible to optimize css animations with javascript , I'm developing a directive to create dynamic tabs and would like to implement animations between their transitions however css transitions demontram is very slow , there is a way to optimize them . My directive is available at: [tab-nav-bar](https://github.com/1fabiopereira/tabNavBar) this version does not have support for animations, someone would have the idea of ​​how best to implement it.

Comment: Try using the 3d equivalents of the 2d CSS functions, you wouldn't think, but it does help in performance, because the latter ones use hardware acceleration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important thing to look for, when animatin things with CSS (or JS even) is to focus on the correct properties. Some of them cause the entire layout to be redrawn.

**The most important thing to keep in mind is - animate *transform* properties, and not the *'left','right','width'* etc.**

You can read more about smooth animations [in this article](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/animating_movement_smoothly_using_css.htm) and a list of best properties to animate is found [here](https://csstriggers.com/).

Another way to use effective animations is to use a js animation library - like GSAP. It has a simple syntax and is very effective - here's a small [demo of it's basic capabilities](http://codepen.io/GreenSock/full/kingu/)

Here's a small example of the GSAP syntax:

```
//pulsate the box using scaleX and scaleY
TweenMax.to(elementSelector, 1.2, {
 scaleX:0.8, 
 scaleY:0.8, 
 force3D:true, 
 yoyo:true, 
 repeat:-1, 
 ease:Power1.easeInOut
});
```

And here's the [home page of GSAP](https://greensock.com/get-started-js)